# Is there a better solution for manipulating one value across multiple functions other than global variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, game-development

I’m creating a text based adventure game in Python and for the the state of character and amount of one item I’m using global variables, but I’ve heard it’s not the best solution and I can’t seem to find one solid answer.

Comment: Using global variables is not good practice. It gets messy very quickly. Use classes instead.

Comment: Welcome aboard, but maybe post a *simplified* version of what you are doing?  This is not easily answerable here, aside from “Globals are the worst.  Ugh!” generalities.

Answer (score 1):

You have heard correctly. Global variables should always be avoided.

For the purposes of your project, I recommend you look into Object Orientated Programming (OOP) in Python. This is a better way of keeping track of the state of objects in your program.

Comment: *Mutable* global state should be avoided. Things like `print` are global variables.